# How to restore backup configurations of deja-dup

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

How can I restore backup configurations of `deja-dup`?

I formatted my Ubuntu machine and I forgot to copy the old configurations.

Comment: Sorry, but what configurations? If you didn't backup the configurations, how you expect to recover them?

Comment: I was using Areca as a backup solution; It has import/export workspace feature (configurations) while I didn't see this kind of feature in deja-dup so I supposed it stores the configurations somewhere in the backup metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the missed configuration file in:

`~/.config/dconf/user`

Thank you guys for help.

`~/.gconf/apps/deja-dup/%gconf.xml`
No longer available in Ubuntu

Comment: Thx, I also found this guide useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/199836/293199

Answer (score 2):

The configuration of deja-dup is stored in `~/.gconf/apps/deja-dup/%gconf.xml` (thats a hidden directory in your home directory). I am certain that this file got backed up too.

Comment: `~/.gconf/apps/deja-dup/%gconf.xml` is incorrect path... see the result of ls `mbnoimi@mbnoimi-pc:~/.gconf > ls -Rh
.:
desktop

./desktop:
%gconf.xml  gnome

./desktop/gnome:
%gconf.xml  url-handlers

./desktop/gnome/url-handlers:
chrome  ftp  %gconf.xml  http  https

./desktop/gnome/url-handlers/chrome:
%gconf.xml

./desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ftp:
%gconf.xml

./desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http:
%gconf.xml

./desktop/gnome/url-handlers/https:
%gconf.xml
mbnoimi@mbnoimi-pc:~/.gconf > `

Comment: @mbnoimi that looks strange - here the output is much longer - please look at (and post) the output of `find .gconf -iname "deja*"`.